# Показать месяцы и годы от старого к новому

Tags: php, дата

Не пойму где ошибся, хочу вывести месяцы за год, но начиная со старых.
пишу:

```
$datestart = date("m.Y",strtotime("-1 years"));
for($mm = 1; $mm < 12; $mm++):
   $month = date($datestart, strtotime('+$mm month'));
   $month.'<br>';
endfor;
```

но в итоге `$month` так и остается равен `$datestart`

Comment: Что значит "начиная со старых"? Старых... чего!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А, если подойти с другой стороны, то для этой задачи можно использовать `DateInterval`:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('-1 year');
$month = new DateInterval('P1M');
do {
  $dateTime->add($month);
  echo $dateTime->format('Y-m') . PHP_EOL;
} while($dateTime < new DateTime());
```

Или ещё красивее с `DatePeriod`:

```
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod(new DateTime('-1 year'), new DateInterval('P1M'), new DateTime('now'));
foreach ($datePeriod as $date) {
  echo $date->format('Y-m') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Правда в этом варианте текущий месяц потерялся, надо поиграться немного.

Answer (score 2):

Если брать во внимание только ваш код, то ошибки видется как минимум две:

> strtotime('+$mm month'))

Чтобы переменная интерпретировалась как переменная нужны двойные кавычки вместо одинарных.

> $month = date($datestart,strtotime('+$mm month'));

В функцию [date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) первым параметром нужно передавать формат даты, а не саму дату.

Т.е. в итоге одну строку поправить:

```
$month = date('Y-m', strtotime("+$mm month"));
```